# I can only install one application in the Hololens

Tags: hololens

I am trying to install several applications in the Hololens. My problem arises when I try to install the second application. Since immediately afterwards the first one is deleted.

Thank you

Comment: Where did you install these apps from? Is it installed from Microsoft store or from Visual Studio?

Comment: I create the solution in Unity and the install with Visual Studio 2017

Comment: When you try to deploy the same solution, If you already have an existing build on the HoloLens,it will reinstall the newer version.

Comment: They are two totally independent projects, each with its solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UWP application distinguishes from each other by globally unique identifier, which is defined in the Package.appxmanifest file.

You can right click the Package.appxmanifest file, then click [Open With], and select [XML (Text) Editor] in the pop-up window. After opening the file, check if the **Identity** tag is different.

Comment: are you speaking about this line? 
<Identity Name="Template3D" Publisher="CN=DefaultCompany" Version="1.0.0.0" />

in those solutions have the same Indentity name. That is the problem?

Comment: @UrkoSanchezOrtiz Yes, Apps with the same Identity will be treated as the same app